# POST source-items for update returns 404

Tags: magento2, api, 404

I am trying to update the quantity of products using the rest api call: ***{HostUrl}/rest/default/V1/inventory/source-items*** with the below data:

```
{
  "sourceItems": [
    {
      "sku": "EXAMPLE_SKU",
      "quantity": 4,
      "status": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this is returning a 404 response saying that the route cannot be found. The route appears to be correct according to the Magento 2.4 static api documentation.

Other routes such as ***{HostUrl}/rest/V1/store/storeViews*** work without a problem and the permissions for modifying products/inventory have been given, so I'm at a dead end to understanding why this isn't working.

Any solution or advice will be massively appreciated :)

Comment: Do you have permission to the Magento_InventoryApi::source resource?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: @That1Guy I found out that the bulk API was only added in Magento 2.4, found out that the client wasn't actually using 2.4. So make sure you are using the right version. Also, just a heads up, you require some extensions to be installed for it to work, although I cannot remember what ones are required anymore.

Comment: Thanks, @ZakDowsett - I appreciate the response. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Remove **default** from the url `{HostUrl}/rest/default/V1/inventory/source-items`.

Comment: Hi Rahul, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: Have you checked with this url `{HostUrl}/rest/V1/inventory/source-items` ?

Comment: Hi Rahul, yes I tried that. I got the same 404 response.

Answer (score 0):

as per the devdocs, https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/inventory/manage-source-items/#assign-products-to-a-source

the `source_code` param is also needed, regardless of if you're using multiple sources. you can get a list of all sources with `/rest/V1/inventory/sources`

example:

```
{
  "sourceItems": [{
    "sku": "myproduct",
    "source_code": "home_source",
    "quantity": "521",
    "status": 1
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following module is present and enabled in your `app/etc/config.php`

- `Magento_InventoryApi`